# Meteor: Deps.changed() not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this form which, let say, I create a ToDo item with, so I created the following:

```
window.myApp = {
    create: {
        dep: new Deps.Dependency(),
        todo: {},
        reset: function () {
            this.todo = {};
            this.dep.changed();
        }
    }
};

Template.createToDo.todo = function () {
    window.myApp.create.dep.depend();
    return window.myApp.create.todo;
};
```

I'm using `Template.createToDo.todo` to fill the form.

(The reason I'm using a namespace variable is because I need this variable in other Templates as well. If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know!)

I can save a todo, the problem is that when I call the `reset` function the template/html doesn't change back to an empty form. Here is the code that listens for the submit/save of that form

```
Template.createToDo.events = {
    'click [save]' : function () {
        Meteor.call('saveTodo', formData());
        window.myApp.create.reset();
    }
};
```

Does someone understand why this doesn't work?

Comment: I think I know whats going on here, the binding is one way :) So changes to the form do not apply to the `window.myApp.create.todo`